# Assigning multiple associations with Simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I understand how to implement a single `has_many` association using simple_form, but how do you assign an additional association from another model object?

In my code, I'm creating model object `@opportunity`. I'm currently assigning a `company_id`, but also need to assign a 'user_id.

`@opportunity` _form.html.erb

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
    <%= simple_form_for([@company, @company.opportunities.build], html: {class: "form-inline"}) do |f| %>
      <%= f.error_notification %>

      <%= f.input :description, label: false, placeholder: 'Create an opportunity', input_html: { class: "span4" } %>
      <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-small'%>
    <% end %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to "Create an Account", new_user_registration_path %>
    to contribute
<% end %>
```

opportunity_controller.rb

```
def create
    @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
    @opportunity = @company.opportunities.create(params[:opportunity])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @opportunity.save
        format.html { redirect_to company_path(@company), notice: 'Opportunity was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @opportunity, status: :created, location: @opportunity }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @opportunity.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your user is logged in, you can change your controller action to the following:

```
def create
  @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
  @opportunity = @company.opportunities.new(params[:opportunity]) # new instead of create
  @opportunity.user = current_user # new

  respond_to do |format|
    if @opportunity.save
      format.html { redirect_to company_path(@company), notice: 'Opportunity was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @opportunity, status: :created, location: @opportunity }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @opportunity.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```